# Using Mongo: should we create an index tailored to each type of high-volume query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongomapper

We have two types of high-volume queries. One looks for docs involving 5 attributes: a date (lte), a value stored in an array, a value stored in a second array, one integer (gte), and one float (gte).

The second includes these five attributes plus two more.

Should we create two compound indices, one for each query? Assume each attribute has a high cardinality.

If we do, because each query involves multiple arrays, it doesn't seem like we can create an index because of Mongo's restriction. How do people structure their Mongo databases in this case?

We're using MongoMapper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indexes for queries after the first ranges in the query the value of the additional index fields drops significantly.

Conceptually, I find it best to think of the addition fields in the index pruning ever smaller sub-trees from the query.  The first range chops off a large branch, the second a smaller, the third smaller, etc.  My general rule of thumb is only the first range from the query in the index is of value.

The caveat to that rule is that additional fields in the index can be useful to aid sorting returned results.

For the first query I would create a index on the two array values and then which ever of the ranges will exclude the most documents.  The date field is unlikely to provide high exclusion unless you can close the range (lte and gte).  The integer and float is hard to tell without knowing the domain.

If the second query's two additional attributes also use ranges in the query and do not have a significantly higher exclusion value then I would just work with the one index.

Rob.